# Create an L-shaped border with round corners using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is the picture of the desired solution (note round corners):

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/cBwh8/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/cBwh8/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/cBwh8/3/

Comment: Dude, do the work yourself! This is the third time I've seen you ask this same question on here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922387/create-an-l-shaped-border-using-html-and-css-is-it-possible

Comment: Is this a fluid or fixed layout? If it's fixed, use an image. If it's fluid, please specify which portions should expand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think I'd ever approach a problem like this with just markup and no images, but since you asked:

http://jsfiddle.net/dcePR/